# Boundary point in MIP using inclusive inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I want to write if-else condition in linear programming and the only method I can think of is using MIP.
I have to write a binary variable called b so that

```
If a>2 then b=1 else (when a<=2) b=0
```

If my application, the solver can only use inclusive inequality.
Either `>` or `<` cannot be used.
First I do:

```
 a>2 => b=1
```

I formulate this as:

```
a<=2+M*b
```

Using the big-M constraint
Then I do:

```
 a<=2 => b=0
```

I formulate this as:

```
a>=2-M*(1-b)
```

I want to have when `a=2=>b=0` while in both cases a is unconstrained.

I could add a 0.01 term so that `a<=2.01-M*b` but why happens when a =2.001?

Is there any more neat way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't see there is a way to do this. Geometrically, the linear programming like this is to cut off the possible values of a given convex set. However, $a$ is not even bounded.

Comment: Your first "big M" constraint currently reads $a\le 2-M*b$. I think you want $a\le 2+M*b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $a$ is not integer, you cannot do exactly what you want. (This is a FAQ in integer programming.) What you can do is partition the domain of $a$ so that $a\le 2 \implies b=0$ and $a\ge 2+\epsilon \implies b=1$, where $\epsilon > 0$ is chosen small (but not so small that it looks like 0 to within floating point arithmetic tolerances). The cost of this is that the interval $(0,\epsilon)$ is removed from the domain of $a$.

Comment: Thank you.  (0,ϵ) interval could be an issue. I am seeking whether somebody could have the way not to involve  ϵ term.

Comment: When you fix the values of the integer variables, the remaining problem should be a linear program, or at least a "well-behaved" convex optimization problem. Well-behaved implies closed feasible region. If you avoid the $\epsilon$ hack, then the subproblem with $b=1$ has a feasible region that is not closed (because $a$ can be arbitrarily close to 2 but cannot equal 2).